# Multiline regex pattern to delete blank lines

Tags: regex, vim, multiline, blank-line

```
/* Comments for code... */

if (...) {

}
```

I need to delete the blank line between the comment and the `if`:

```
/* Comments for code... */
if (...) {

}
```

I am currently using the following regex:

```
/\*\/\ze\n^$\n[ ]*if
```

- `\*//`: end of comment (`*/`)
- `^$`: blank line before `if`
- `[ ]*if`: spaces and an `if`

As I use `\ze`, cursor finally points to `*/`. How should I do?

Comment: And your question is?!

Comment: command to delete the blank line between pattern(end of comment)and if statement

Answer (score 2):

try this line:

```
%s#\*/[\s\r\n]*#*/\r#
```

it will make

```
/* Comments for code... */





if (...) {

}
/* Comments for code... */






else{


}
```

into:

```
/* Comments for code... */
if (...) {

}
/* Comments for code... */
else{


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `\zs` as well.

This worked for me:

```
:%s/\*\/\zs\n*[ ]*\zeif/\r/g
```

Explaination:

```
%s - substitution on the entire file
\*\/ - end of comment
\zs - start of match
\n*[ ]* - eol and spaces
\ze - end of match
if - followed by if
/\n/ - replacement
g - global regex (multiline)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:g+*/+j
```

is much quicker but probably too broad.

You could do something like the following:

```
:g+*/\_\s*if+j
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex can achieve this:

`:%s/\(\/*\)\(\n\+\)\(if\)/\1\r\3`

The `\(\/*\)` match the comment line

`\(\n\+\)` match any empty lines below till

`\(if\)` that match `if` line